# escape single quote in a string and pass this string value to java script function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where I have to escape single quote in a string and pass this string value to java script function

Ex: `Mario O'Brian`

```
<a href="javascript:goToMethod('<c:out value={myName"}/>'}

function goToMethod(myName){}
```

problem is I am not able to remove single quote . I tried using fn:replace tag but it has got its own limitations. fn tag is not  working as expected in Websphere.Can you suggest me some alternative?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to remove it or you want to escape it?

Comment: You probably have to escape the value from Java and not from Javascript.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0):

To **escape**

```
myName.replace(/'/g, "\\'"); // escaping \ with \, so used 2x
```

To **remove**

```
myName.replace(/'/g, "");
```

Comment: I tried the above code..it was not working. I am getting error :Expected ')' if this code is used within <c:out tag>